# Android back button leads to root instead of previous activity

Tags: android, back-stack

Ok, I have an app which creates the following back stack:

3. Details Activity
4. Main Activity
5. Login Activity

It's working fine on devices with enough RAM but on older ones I experience a peculiar problem. On such devices each new activity triggers the destruction of the previous one to obtain enough memory. However, pressing the back button on Details Activity leads the user to Login Activity instead of Main Activity. I use the default behavior (no Intent flags or back-stack-related activity attributes in the manifest file). According to my understanding of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) the default behavior of the back button is to bring you back to the previous activity, not the root one. What am I missing?

Edit:
Here is how I declare my activities in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BoardViewActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/activity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TaskDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_details">
    </activity>
```

LoginActivity starts BoardViewActivity:

```
    Intent intentBoardView = new Intent(this, BoardViewActivity.class);
    intentBoardView.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intentBoardView);
    finish();
```

Then a fragment of BoardViewActivity starts TaskDetailsActivity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskDetailsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TASKDETAILS);
```

Then in TaskDetailsActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case (android.R.id.home):
        TaskDetailsActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
        return true;

    case (R.id.action_save):
        save();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

It doesn't matter if I use the back button or the software home(up) button - it always goes back to LoginActivity.

Comment: How do u declare your activities and call new instances ? could u show us your manifest and how do u call MainActivity and Details Activity ?

Comment: Added some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Finish app Activity using BackPressed.

Comment: Adding finish() to onBackPressed() didn't change the behavior.